# Overflow - y is breaking row in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a custom-class CSS class which I applied in the col div. That column contains dynamic images, which is why I used a vertical scrollbar.

On a desktop, it displays correctly. However, in mobile view it is broken or exceeds a row or section.

How can I apply vertical scrollbar  that will not affect col in mobile view?

In short my overflow floating over the screen in mobile view.

```css
.custom-class {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12">
    <section class="py-5 header">
      <div class="container py-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5 p-0">
                    <div class="col-md-12 custom-class"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise the snippet demo with some content to show the problem. Note that it's a bit odd to put a container inside a column, and columns shouldn't be directly nested (there should always be a row between levels). Maybe review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#nesting).

Comment: Also, absolute position can be troublesome, especially when applied to primary grid element. It's probably better to apply it to column _content_ instead, or use other techniques. I'd offer suggestions but I really have no idea what your overall goal is here. Please see [ask] and make improvements to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was so simple. `removing` absolute position worked for me. Absolute position disturb in mobile view.